# Rails: creating RESTful web services with XML and JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services

I'm curious about the best practice in creating web services which support both XML and JSON output.

At the moment, my service is very XML oriented (see below), but I want to add JSON support.

Here's one example:

```
  def create
    render_authentication_error and return if !@user
    render_parameter_not_found_error("item") and return if params[:item].nil?
    render_parameter_not_found_error("name") and return if params[:item][:name].blank?
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])
    begin 
      if !@item.save 
        raise "Item not saved" 
      end 
    rescue 
      render_resource_not_saved_error("Error saving #{@item.name}")
    else 
      render_resource_created(:location => item_path(@item))
    end 
  end
```

There are helper methods in ApplicationController that renders XML accordingly.

I'm not sure how to go about adding `respond_to` block here since I need to do validations. Is there a way to retrieve `format` in a controller outside of `respond_to` block so that I can output error messages in a given format as well?

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :json => @item.to_json }
  format.xml { render :xml => @item }
end
```

Let me know if you need any clarification.

**UPDATE** I suppose I'm looking something similar to [respond_with](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2009/08/06/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with/) in Rails 3. I'm on Rails 2.3 still.. I wonder if it can be done in 2.3?

**UPDATE** [Inherited Resources](http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) seems like what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace @person with @item, but there's the idea:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @person.save 
    format.html { 
      flash[:notice] = 'Person was successfully created.'
      redirect_to @person 
    }
    format.js { render :json => @person, :status => :created, :location => @person} 
    format.xml  { render :xml => @person, :status => :created, :location => @person }
  else
    format.html { render :partial => "form" }
    format.js { render :json=>@person.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @person.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid repeating chucks of code like that. Also rendering output from validation failure won't be elegant this way.. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well ok. However, that's pretty much the standard for rails right now. Also, rendering the .errors seems to be really elegant, I like it alot. Good luck!

Comment: I updated the post, but it seems Inherited Resources library is what I was looking for. I'll mark your answer since it's the proper way to go about in pre 3.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little complicated, but it can be achieved. See here:

http://shifteleven.com/articles/2006/11/26/drying-up-respond_to

Also, maybe you can look at `request.format` and pass it? I am pretty sure it will have the format requested...

Comment: Looks interesting.. and experimental. Not quite convinced to try it out. I'll look into request.format. Thanks for the answer.